# Getting rows of a day by timestamp, Day/Minute of certain pattern

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

```
id   name     quantity    timestamp
1    item1     2         2015-06-01 20:00:00
2    item2     5         2015-06-01 22:30:00
3    item3     2         2015-06-02 20:00:00
4    item4     7         2015-06-02 20:30:00
5    item5     9         2015-06-02 21:30:00
```

This is an example database, 'timestamp' is in datetime format and contains varying values. Note that the table contains various date and time data. How do i get all the rows of one day and of certain minute(above eg: 30) only, eg how can i select all the rows with timestamp  2015-06-01 **:30:00, here ** = hour any help, thanks.

Comment: did you tried something? Please share your sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATE` & `MINUTE` functions -

```
SELECT * from your_table WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = '2015-06-02' AND MINUTE(`timestamp`) = 30
```

Comment: Thanks for response and it solves my problem but how do i add where clause? Can we? like where quanatity = 2.

Comment: Add another `AND quantity = 2`

Comment: I was messing with my working database and i slipped that, yes now its totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write follow query:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table_Name WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2015-06-01' AND TIME(timestamp) LIKE '%:30:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for response .